How to increase a font size of resultset of Oracle apex?
While creating n interactive report in oracle apex .. I want to see the result in enlarged form.
i.e. I want to increase the fontsize to say 18 for a displayed result.
How to increase a fhontsize of a column value in oracle apex ?
I tried to find a solution online but failed
Please help

I tried as suggested but not working

This is an example based on Scott's DEPT table.
Interactive report's query is simple:
select dname, loc from dept

Edit dname column's "HTML expression" property and put something like this into it:
<p style="font-size:xx-large">#DNAME#</p>

Result is then

See other valid font size options e.g. here.

not working sir

It is, as my example shows.

hi ... Done sir... issue is resolved thank you .....

This can be achieved by modifying the font that is used by APEX. APEX uses css variables to control the layout. So ... check the page in the browser inspector to find out what font is used. In Chrome: right-click in the report and scroll in the styles pane to find what looks like a variable that controls the font:

In the screenshot you'll see that it's a css class called "font-size" controlled by a css variable "--a-gv-font-size".
With this info you have enough to adjust the interactive report font. I used a report on the emp table with a static id of "ir-emp".
The in page attributes > CSS > Inline, set the css variable for the report.

And...the magic happens:


I created Id as hemu

but not able to find out the variabale .. tried through inspect elements

how do I add screenshot in a comment?

You can't add screenshots in a comment. Have you tried my code ? What version of APEX are you on ?
